# How to add opentrace interceptor to restTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, zipkin, opentracing

I want to trace all http requests sent via RestTemplate in my spring(not boot) application.

I've found class `BraveClientHttpRequestInterceptor`

I have concern because this class is deprecated and I don't see any recommended alternative. If you know this alternative - please let me know.

So I decided to try with deprecated `BraveClientHttpRequestInterceptor` but I didn't find how instatiate `BraveClientHttpRequestInterceptor`

I have following configuration:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(BraveClientHttpRequestInterceptor bci) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(bci);
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to set loglevel for `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` to `DEBUG`.

You might also find some other possible solutions on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-logging

Please let me know if this is useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is absolutely irrelevant with my question) Tracing is not logging, please read https://opentracing.io/docs/overview/

Comment: I see it now. Sorry for beeing too fast! Good luck in solving your issue!

Answer (score 0):

You must inject a RestTemplate using RestTemplateBuilder

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.build();
}
```

Using [this library](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-web) you should have [this configuration](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-web/blob/master/opentracing-spring-web-starter/src/main/java/io/opentracing/contrib/spring/web/starter/RestTemplateTracingAutoConfiguration.java) that triggers and add the interceptor to the RestBuilder. If it doesn't trigger you can do it manually